# Is there any way to indicate multiple answers as correct?

Tags: support

I often get multiple answers which are all good and usable.  It would seem I should be able to indicate that (in the case of 2 of them) both are accepted.  Question 37882 is a current case of this.  Can I mark them both as acceptable (or accepted)?

Comment: No you can't. You can comment under each to say that it was helpful or you can place a bounty to "reward" (if you _really_ like it), but you can accept only one.